# Convert MembershipProvider from OBDC to SQL throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, membership-provider

I'm getting an exception thrown at `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` when I debug.

*CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IAsyncResult' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'.*

This is a custom MembershipProvider derived from the MSDN sample membership provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx) with the username value calling the Email database field rather than a separate Username entry, and the connection was changed from an Odbc to a SQL connection.

```
    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserID, Email, PasswordQuestion," +
            " Comment, IsApproved, IsLockedOut, CreationDate, LastLoginDate," +
            " LastActivityDate, LastPasswordChangedDate, LastLockedOutDate" +
            " FROM Users WHERE Email = ? AND ApplicationName = ?", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = username;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = m_ApplicationName;

        MembershipUser u = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                u = GetUserFromReader(reader);

                if (userIsOnline)
                {
                    SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Users " +
                        "SET LastActivityDate = ? " +
                        "WHERE Email = ? AND Applicationname = ?", conn);

                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastActivityDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = username;
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = m_ApplicationName;

                    updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried specify parameter name inside the sqlcommand? the question mark seems strange to me

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserID, Email, PasswordQuestion," +
    " Comment, IsApproved, IsLockedOut, CreationDate, LastLoginDate," +
    " LastActivityDate, LastPasswordChangedDate, LastLockedOutDate" +
    " FROM Users WHERE Email = @email AND ApplicationName = @applicationname", conn);
```

Comment: That did prevent the exception. However it returned "Your account was not created. Please try again." on the ErrorMessage Literal control in the CreateUserWiard. Perhaps that solved it. I'll have to step it through and see where it's stopping.

Comment: so it's on the right track, you have to do some further investigation, good luck

Comment: You had good reason to not like ?s. They aren't supported with Sql.

Comment: Yeah, i have only seen @param in sqlcommand, not ?s. How is your debugging with the new error?

Comment: Still working out various kinks, but outside the subject of this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Dataadaptor instead of a reader?  You aren't closing the reader properly anyways, which may cause memory issues on your website.  Honestly, i almost always have issues with readers except for very specific cases.

Comment: How am I not closing it properly? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: easiest way to close it is to use 'using'.  using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){  ...your code...}

Comment: additionally, both your sqlconnection and sqlcommand don't have close/dispose statements on them either.  You can use the 'using' on them as well.  or a try/finally block if you prefer

Comment: Found this on MSDN:

_The Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server does not support the question mark (?) placeholder for passing parameters to a SQL Statement_ [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)